# Search is indexing HTML tag and attribute names

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search result summaries appear to have raw html where there should be links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/search-result-summaries-appear-to-have-raw-html-where-there-should-be-links)

Something I noticed while searching MSO: it looks like a question's html markup is being indexed as searchable content.  Try [searching for "hr"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hr) and you'll see several questions that use horizontal rules in their markup, even if the text doesn't mention "hr" anywhere.  The same works for ["img"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=img) and ["href"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=href) too.

I found [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/search-result-summaries-appear-to-have-raw-html-where-there-should-be-links).  In [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/search-result-summaries-appear-to-have-raw-html-where-there-should-be-links/11371#11371) to that, he says this is by design because you'd want `<a href="http://www.example.com/perl-hacking">a link</a>` to be returned in a search for "perl hacking", even though the link's text doesn't mention it.  Fair enough, but is it possible to index only the attribute values, and hide the tag and attribute names?

http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/5347/hrsearch.png

Comment: no, it is not possible in practice...